# Ошибка при запуске в монго

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, koa.js

Запускаю проект и выдает эту ошибку

```
yarn run v1.3.2
$ babel-node app/server
C:\koa.site\api\node_modules\config\lib\config.js:194
    throw new Error('Configuration property "' + property + '" is not defined');
    ^

Error: Configuration property "mongo.uri" is not defined
    at Config.get (C:\koa.site\api\node_modules\config\lib\config.js:194:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:/koa.site/api/app/config.js:5:51)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at loader (C:\koa.site\api\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\koa.site\api\node_mod
ules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Пишет что то про config.js
Вот что в нем

```
import config from 'config';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || config.get('port');
const MONGO_URI = process.env.MONGO_URI || config.get('mongo.uri');
export {
  PORT,
  MONGO_URI,
};

{
  "env": "development",
  "mongo": {
    "url": "mongo-development"
  }
}
```

Comment: Покажи свои конфиги, тот, откуда берет mongo.uri

Comment: @daedra добавил ниже

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
  "env": "development",
  "mongo": {
    "url": "mongo-development"
  }
}
```

В этом фрагменте замени url на uri

Comment: Спасибо, не заметил